# Checking tag and associated data in an AEAD cipher in Java

Tags: java, aes, aes-gcm

I need to use AEAD to share information between two users, part of which must be encrypted and part of which should be kept in cleartext.

*Is there an API to check the ciphertext tag and access the associated data once a message has been encrypted with AES/GCM ?*

### In more detail:

I'm using Java 7 with bouncycastle as a provider and I have managed to encrypt and decrypt my data successfully, using the corresponding API:

```
private byte[] encrypt(SecretKey key, byte[] nonce, byte[] message, byte[] associatedData) throws ... {
   Cipher aeadCipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_GCM_NOPADDING);
   aeadCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, kint, new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_MAC_SIZE, nonce);
   aeadCipher.updateAAD(associatedData);
   return aeadCipher.doFinal(message);
}

private byte[] decrypt(SecretKey key, byte[] nonce, byte[] cipherText, byte[] associatedData) throws ... {
   Cipher aeadCipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_GCM_NOPADDING);
   aeadCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, kint, new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_MAC_SIZE, nonce);
   aeadCipher.updateAAD(associatedData);
   return aeadCipher.doFinal(cipherText);
}
```

However, it is my understanding that AES/GCM ciphertexts should already contain the parameters that could affect decryption (nonce and associatedData).
Therefore, I would like to be able to retrieve them from the ciphertext, rather than having to store them alongside the ciphertext and pass them along to the decryption function. Furthermore, I'd like to be able to run integrity checks (computing the tag) and run some checks on the associated data without having to completely decrypt the message.

Is there an API that would allow this and that I might have missed ?

So far, I've checked:

- The Cipher API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html
- This very informative blog post on AES/GCM implementations in Java: http://blog.philippheckel.com/2014/03/01/cipherinputstream-for-aead-modes-is-broken-in-jdk7-gcm/

Comment: Note that CCM is defined for "packets" and has a clear order and definition in octets of the parameters, the AAD and the "payload". It's also horrible to program though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no implicit format that stores all the input data of GCM in a specific location. The Java API is already a bit strange in
the sense that it automatically places the tag at the end. This makes the
algorithm more compatible with the `Cipher` class, but in principle the tag just
needs to be kept with the ciphertext - where does not matter. Now you have the
issue that you don't know where the AAD ends and the ciphertext starts for instance.

So what you can do is either to create your own format (maybe your AAD has a
static size, so you can just concatenate) or you can use a predefined container format.
There is an [internet draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-smime-cms-aes-ccm-and-gcm-03)
that specifies how to use both modes in the Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS).
The AAD can then be stored in authenticated atributes, which should also include the required
parameters (including the IV comprising of the nonce).

If you feel masochistic you could also try and use XML-encryption with GCM mode, but beware of the many pitfalls with regard to verifying XML authenticity (e.g. beware that you are actually verifying the data you are going to use).

Bouncy Castle seems to offer support for CMS using GCM.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look into using CMS.

Answer (score 3):

Since the Java API  automatically places the tag at the end, you only have to extract this tag from the your encryption result as follow:

```
private byte[] getTag(SecretKey key, byte[] nonce, byte[] message,   byte[] associatedData) throws ... {
   Cipher aeadCipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_GCM_NOPADDING);
   aeadCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, kint, new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_MAC_SIZE, nonce);
   aeadCipher.updateAAD(associatedData);
   byte[] encrypted = aeadCipher.doFinal(message);
   // Assuming you have an AAD_SIZE = 128 bits (16 bytes)
   return Arrays.copyOfRange (encrypted, encrypted.length-16, encrypted.length)
```

}